# How to locally automate jupyter lab by dynamically creating cells, setting file paths, and executing?

Tags: python, shell, automation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm automating a bunch of tasks locally with python and shell scripts. I've created a python socket server and clients so I can automate the execution of scripts in different shells and envs. It's not fully-functional, but I can fire up shells, run scripts, and have them connect to the server before executing. One app uses jupyter lab and notebooks. I'm not finding much about how to automate this for what I need.

I tried converting my `ipynb` file to a `py` file thinking I could treat it as an ordinary python script, then use a watch folder, load the file names in a dict, and just script in some loops with variable file names, but that doesn't seem to be the case—at least I haven't found anything discussing how to do it with notebooks.

This is what I need to accomplish (programmatically):

- Open a new shell, activate env and launch jupyter lab (this I can do)
- Connect jupyter lab to the socket server (guessing I can do this in a cell?)
- Create a cell with a command that loops through each file in a specific folder with args
- Execute all cells in the notebook
- Send a message back to socket server that things have completed

Whether or not I need to convert the `ipynb` to a `py` file or automate jupyter lab doesn't matter to me, as long as I can automate it. Point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: There are many ways to execute code in Jupyter with parametrization, from enterprise-level UI ([Elyra pipelines](https://elyra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/pipelines.html)), through dedicated Python tooling ([papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill)), to full UI automation with [galata](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/tree/master/galata) or [robotframework-jupyterlibrary](https://github.com/robots-from-jupyter/robotframework-jupyterlibrary). I am not sure if this is a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: why to create new cell for every file? Why not run normal `for`-loop in one cell. Maybe better try to do all in one cell and if you can do this in one cell then you can put it in normal .py file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @krassowski. I'll check them out. lol @furas, I actually meant to write `Create a cell, then for each file in a folder, etc etc`. I'll modify the question. The folder may change, but now I'm opting to use the same folder and move things when they're done to simplify it. I don't know if I can do the entire thing in one cell, but will look into it.

Comment: @krassowski Elyra is probably overkill for what I'm doing, but very cool for complex designs. I like the modular mapping of things. Robot Framework is almost identical to my list in functionality. One of them should do the trick. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being new to jupyter notebooks, I wasn't understanding properly how they work. I didn't realize there was a flag when converting to completely strip out all the data except for the raw code. `--no-prompt`

Running this command will completely convert the `ipynb` file to the raw code `py`

```sh
jupyter nbconvert --to script --no-prompt myfile.ipynb
```

Once you do that, they are just like any other python script. I was able to easily add in all my code and have the script working as needed now.

That being said, the suggested tools by @krassowski would be fantastic for more complex projects in the future, especially in a case when you don't want to convert the notebooks.